# How to enable resizing of a window in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtgui, qtwidgets

I'm new to Qt and I'm trying to figure out a way to auto-resize in Qt. The goal is for the user to be able to drag the window to make it bigger and everything resizes to the size of the window. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: use QLayout which will automatically resize in widgets inside

Comment: What is QLayout if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I suggest you read the [tutorial on layouts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: In Qt widget UI, almost every child widget should ne on a layout, so yeah, better to learn them. But, an important question: are you creating the GUI by writing C++ yourself, or by using the Designer? You should add that info to the question.

Comment: I have been using the designer. From what I have seen when you code in C++ it expands by itself. I think I might try recoding all of the widgets; it's just that I wanted to avoid it if possible. I wasn't sure if there was an option to make the applet resize because that just seems like such a standard feature.